# Transform a Hierarchical Dataframe into a nested list of dictionaries Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, networkx

My data can be downloaded [here](https://simplemaps.com/data/us-cities) and it looks like this.

[image]

My goal is to build a network where the nodes are State, city, and county, sized by population. This will be part of an app, so the node level selection will be dynamic, any combination of State, city, and county. [Here](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/collapsible-force-directed-tree/) is the visualization I want to achieve.
The data would need to look like this:

```
[{name: "state1",
  children:[{name: "county1",
             children:[{name: "city1",
                        population: "13000"
                       },
                       {name: "city2",
                        population: "10000"
                       },
            {name: "county2",
             children:[{name: "city1",
                        population: "1000"
                       },
                       {name: "city2",
                        population: "100000"
                       }]
            }]
},{name: "state2",
  children:[{name: "county1",
             children:[{name: "city1",
                        population: "13000"
                       },
                       {name: "city2",
                        population: "10000"
                       },
            {name: "county2",
             children:[{name: "city1",
                        population: "1000"
                       },
                       {name: "city2",
                        population: "100000"
                       }]
            }]
}]
```

This is what I've tried so far.

```
import pandas as pd
from benedict import benedict

# read in the data
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\m316375\\Downloads\\uscities.csv")

# Using Benedict to create a nested list
df_benedict = df[["state_name","city", "county_name", "population"]]
node_id = ["state_name", "county_name","city"]
df_benedict['dict_path'] = df[node_id].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)

d = benedict()
d.keypath_separator = '_'

for row in df_benedict.iterrows():
    dict_path = row[1]["dict_path"]
    d[dict_path] = row[1]["population"]

##### First Attempt ########
#looping through the nested dictionary
state_children = []
city_children = []
county_children = []
full_children = []
dict_list = []
counter = 0
for state, v0 in d.items():
    #print(f"state={state}, population={v0})")
    for city, v1 in v0.items():
        for county, v2 in v1.items():
            county_children.append({"name": city,
                                  "value": v2})
            counter += 1
            # print(counter)
            if counter > len(v1.items()):
                city_children.append({"name": county,
                                        "children": county_children})
                county_children = []
                counter = 0
                state_children = [{"name": city,
                                "children": city_children}]
                dict_list.append({"name": state,
                                  "children": state_children})
```

PROBLEM: My approach is not dynamic. If I want to only display state and cities, I would need to remove one of the for loops. Not ideal.

Comment: kindly fix the data u shared (gives error : ```unexpected EOF while parsing```) and post ur expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy, I have the link to download the data. see the first sentence of the question. The output is the nested list of dictionary, as seen in the first code chunk. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got what you need, although it's a bit unwieldy. Given than the data from the link you provided is loaded into dataframe `df`, the code is as follows:

First, groupby, moving state, city, and county to multiindex and leaving population as the only column:

```
df_gr = df.groupby(['state_name', 'county_name', 'city']).sum()['population']
```

Then we can build a desired dictionary using dictionary comprehension:

```
resulting_dict = {level0: {level1: {level2: df_gr.xs([level0, level1, level2]) for level2 in df_gr.xs([level0, level1]).reset_index().groupby(['city']).sum().index} for level1 in df_gr.xs([level0]).reset_index().groupby(['county_name', 'city']).sum().index.levels[0]} for level0 in df_gr.index.levels[0]}
```

Basically we use use `.xs()` to return a cross-section of the dataframe at the desired level. We also ensure that we don't loop over combinations of levels that don't exist. The `.reset_index()` followed by `.groupby()` is used to get the index of the cross-section instead of the whole dataframe (since using `.index.levels` after `.xs()` returns levels of the whole dataframe and I don't know of any easier way to make it return index for the cross-section only).

You can tailor the dictionary comprehension to the desired format of output.

Comment: I already have a nested dictionary. I need it in a nested list of dictionary, as seen in the first code chunk.